# Ruby on Rails relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is homework, just so that's mentioned.

I have project called AdventCalendar, which is supposed to be an Advent Calendar, (obviously).
I have made it possible to log in/ log out, or create new users. Once you have logged in you may create Calendars (Advent calendars). Each calendar has many days, and a day belongs to one calendar. Also, a user can create many calendars.

So, what I want is to make it possible for a user to share their calendars with other users if they want to. I'm kind of stuck and don't know where to go from here. I thought maybe to add a

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

to calendar, and likewise:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :calendars
```

to users..

I just don't know how to implement it.
Any tips, or help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're right on point here. Though I think its a little less complicated. Calendars do not have to have many users. The relationship, hierarchically is ok with just users having calendars. Then, for calendars, create a polymorphic join table to allow a calendar to have many users associated with.

```
#user.rb

 has_many    :calendars


#calendar.rb

 belongs_to  :many_users, :polymorphic => true
 has_many    :users, :as => :many_users
```

Your calendar table should have a `many_users_id`, and a `user_id` field.